Dataflow job successfully completes but Airflow tasks thinks that it is still running
We recently upgraded to Airflow 2.6.3. After this upgrade our Airflow tasks didn't complete after dataflow job completion. We are using DataflowCreateJavaJobOperator. Our pipeline has pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish() setup.
return DataflowCreateJavaJobOperator(
        task_id=task_id,
        jar=jar,
        dataflow_default_options=dataflow_default_options,
        options=options,
        gcp_conn_id=gcp_conn_id,
        dag=dag
    )

Airflow task logs shows dataflow job completed successfully but tasks not marked as success in ver 2.6.3
[2024-06-11 21:15:03.710199+00:00] {beam.py:114} INFO - [INFO] 2024-06-11T21:15:01.570Z: Finished operation Write to BigQuery/BatchLoads/SinglePartitionWriteTables/GroupByKey/Read+Write to BigQuery/BatchLoads/SinglePartitionWriteTables/GroupByKey/GroupByWindow+Write to BigQuery/BatchLoads/SinglePartitionWriteTables/Values/Values/Map+Write to BigQuery/BatchLoads/SinglePartitionWriteTables/ParDo(GarbageCollectTemporaryFiles)
[2024-06-11 21:15:03.710300+00:00] {beam.py:114} INFO - [DEBUG] 2024-06-11T21:15:01.614Z: Executing success step success228
[2024-06-11 21:15:03.710485+00:00] {beam.py:114} INFO - [INFO] 2024-06-11T21:15:01.687Z: Cleaning up.
[2024-06-11 21:15:03.710550+00:00] {beam.py:114} INFO - [DEBUG] 2024-06-11T21:15:01.731Z: Starting worker pool teardown.
[2024-06-11 21:15:03.710798+00:00] {beam.py:114} INFO - [INFO] 2024-06-11T21:15:01.779Z: Stopping worker pool...
[2024-06-11 21:28:31.805338+00:00] {beam.py:114} INFO - [INFO] 2024-06-11T21:28:30.290Z: Autoscaling: Resized worker pool from 400 to 0.
[2024-06-11 21:28:31.805415+00:00] {beam.py:114} INFO - [INFO] 2024-06-11T21:28:30.336Z: Worker pool stopped.
[2024-06-11 21:28:31.805546+00:00] {beam.py:114} INFO - [DEBUG] 2024-06-11T21:28:30.364Z: Tearing down pending resources...
[2024-06-11 21:28:41.479723+00:00] {beam.py:114} INFO - [INFO] Job 2024-06-11_14_00_12-11268310877205063496 finished with status DONE.
[2024-06-11 21:28:41.488950+00:00] {beam.py:114} INFO - [DEBUG] Closing org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@73700b80, started on Tue Jun 11 20:59:33 UTC 2024
[2024-06-11 21:28:41.491944+00:00] {beam.py:114} INFO - [DEBUG] Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
[2024-06-11 21:28:41.493080+00:00] {beam.py:114} INFO - [INFO] Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'

Airflow task logs shows dataflow job completed successfully and tasks marked as success in ver 2.4.
[2024-06-11, 06:27:53 UTC] {beam.py:132} INFO - [INFO] Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
[2024-06-11, 06:27:53 UTC] {beam.py:132} WARNING - WARNING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
[2024-06-11, 06:27:53 UTC] {beam.py:132} WARNING - WARNING: Illegal reflective access by org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase (file:/tmp/tmpowl7u86qSOQ_SdcOutboundFork.jar) to field java.io.ObjectStreamClass$Caches.localDescs
[2024-06-11, 06:27:53 UTC] {beam.py:132} WARNING - WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase
[2024-06-11, 06:27:53 UTC] {beam.py:132} WARNING - WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
[2024-06-11, 06:27:53 UTC] {beam.py:132} WARNING - WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
[2024-06-11, 06:27:53 UTC] {beam.py:155} INFO - Process exited with return code: 0
[2024-06-11, 06:27:53 UTC] {dataflow.py:425} INFO - Start waiting for done.
[2024-06-11, 06:27:53 UTC] {dataflow.py:385} INFO - Google Cloud DataFlow job trigger-dataflow-db456216e is state: JOB_STATE_DONE
[2024-06-11, 06:27:53 UTC] {taskinstance.py:1402} INFO - Marking task as SUCCESS. dag_id=test, task_id=task1, execution_date=20240610T060000, start_date=20240611T060751, end_date=20240611T062753
[2024-06-11, 06:27:54 UTC] {local_task_job.py:159} INFO - Task exited with return code 0
[2024-06-11, 06:27:54 UTC] {taskinstance.py:2626} INFO - 1 downstream tasks scheduled from follow-on schedule check

We tried to use BeamRunJavaPipelineOperator with below options but still same problem(after changing pipeline.run().waitUntilFinish() to pipeline.run()
   return BeamRunJavaPipelineOperator(
        task_id=task_id,
        runner='DataflowRunner',
        jar=jar,
        default_pipeline_options=dataflow_default_options,
        pipeline_options=options,
        gcp_conn_id=gcp_conn_id,
        dataflow_config=DataflowConfiguration(job_name="{{task.task_id}}",wait_until_finished=True),
        deferrable=deferrable,
        dag=dag
    )

